# Creating a promise in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to create a promise in Angular.  The async function, flQuestionCrud.createNewQuestion(currentQuestionData), allows me to create an entry in the mongoDb collection when I use a callback but I am not able to get the create question data back and I need the _id.  I am now trying to create a promise but the error message is that doWorkAsync.then is not a function.  If this was in express I would use Q.nfcall as that seems to be an easy way to create a promise but this capability does not seem to exist in Angular.  Any suggestions on how to create a promise?

```
  function doWorkAsync() {
        return $timeout(flQuestionCrud.createNewQuestion(currentQuestionData), 10);
    }

    doWorkAsync
        .then(function(questiondata) {
            console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Success " + questiondata);
            console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Success Statement " + questiondata.statement);
            console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Success Question id " + questiondata._id);
            currentQuestionData._id = questiondata._id;
            flQuestionDataService.setNewQuestionId(questiondata._id);
            console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - currentQuestionData._id " + currentQuestionData._id);
            console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - flQuestionDataService.getNewQuestionId() " + flQuestionDataService.getNewQuestionId());
            $state.go('questionUpdate');
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            console.log("flQuestionCrudCtrl - Error " + err);
            $state.go('questionCreate');
        })
        .done();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be `doWorkAsync().then`. You're missing the parenthesis.

It should also be `.catch()` instead of `.fail()`.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the then function but has exposed two other problems.  Error: doWorkAsync(...).then(...).fail is not a function  and Error: data is undefined.  The question is written to the database but I am still not getting back the return question/data.   I might need to post the callback that should be returning the data unless you have some other ideas of these problems.

Comment: Thanks again, that fixed the .fail error but I am still not getting data back. I will create another post with the function that should be returning the data.